# MOM characteristics in REST

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, mom

Recently I read [this](http://windyroad.com.au/2012/01/13/the-chain-of-custody-problem) interesting article about the comparison between REST and MOM.
I know REST is an architectural style while MOMs (JMS server e.g.) basic features includes message persistence and patterns like PUB-SUB.

Can REST be used instead of MOM? I know it will vary from case to case but if so how it can guarantee that no message,data is not lost?